# The array[i+1] has the same value as array[i] even though it shouldn't

Tags: c, arrays

I'm making a code for an assignment, where you are supposed to make a program that checks how many pairs of people can see eachother in a line, depending on their height. I have a code that looks like this:

```
for( int in = 0; in < N-1; in++ )
{
    for( int index = 1; index < N; index++ )
    {
        if( C[in] >= C[in+index] && C[in+index] <= C[in+1+index]  )
        {
            num = num + 1;
        }
        if( C[in] < C[in+index] )
        {
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

C is an array that holds the heights of all people in the line. As you can see, I check from left to right whether or not a person in between two people is shorter or equal height to the people it's between. If that person is, the other two people can see eachother and I increase the amounts of pairs of people that can see eachother. However, there's some weird stuff going on. Let's say my array has 3 elements, 2, 1 and 3 in that order. There should be 3 pairs being able to see eachother (I automatically add the people standing next to eachother a bit earlier in the program), two pairs that stand next to eachother, and the person being 2 in height and the person being 3 in height. When you enter the loop, C[in] should have the value 2, C[in+index] should have the value 1 and C[in+index+1] should have the value 3. However, all of these hold the value 2. The only thing that changes when I step through the loops is that the C[in]value changes when the in++ part is happening from the first for-loop.

I have no idea what's going on, in my head, this should all work. I'm kinda new to programming so please explain thoroughly and don't hate on my programming, this was the best way I could figure out. :P

Thanks for any help! :D

EDIT: Forgot to mention that N stands for the number of people in the line.

Comment: This is a pretty good start. I always tell my students to break down their solutions so that they are solving as few steps as possible at a time - it is way easier to debug that way. Here is what I recommend for your next debugging step: Put the following print statement just after your second for() loop: printf("%d %d %d\n", N, in, index);  This will let you check whether you are really iterating over the right group of people. Pick a small value for N (~4) and look at all the pairs that come out. If you are not getting the pairs you want, adjust and retry. Let us know how it goes.

Comment: So if all array elements hold the same value at entry to the loop, then this suggests that something before this, where you assign values to the array, is wrong.

Comment: `C[in+index]` accesses the array out of its bounds if `in = 0 .. N-2`, `index = 0 .. N-1`.

Comment: Mmmm..... This part: `C[in+index] <= C[in+1+index]` can lead to unexpected behaviour. What happens if `in+index` is much larger than `N` (which could and will happen if the C array has its elements sorted from greatest to lowest)

Answer (score 1):

Your loop bounds are wrong: Both `in` and `index` go up to the end of the array, but you use their sum as an index in `C[in+index]`. This will at some point read past the end of the array, invoking undefined behaviour. Fix this and see if your problem disappears.

Aside:
I would strongly advise you to use a bit more speaking names for your variables. No one reading the name `C` will know that this is an array that is supposed to hold the heights of people... better call it something like `personHeights` which is not very imaginative either, but at least it gives some hints to the reader.

Comment: I changed the code into this: 
`if( C[in] >= C[in+index] && C[in+index] <= C[in+1+index] && in + index + 1 < N && in + index < N )
   {
    num = num + 1;
   }`
this helped for small lines of people. I tested one with 9 that should have turned out to be 16, but it turned out as 17. 

Something else that might be relevant is that the array always is 500 000 elements (the assignment says that's the max), but I only add values to the N first ones.

Comment: In that case, I hope you actually initialize the entire array before use. Other languages implicitly this for you, the `C` dialects won't. Reading uninitialized data is simply reading garbage. But your problem is not the `if` statement, your problem is the second `for` statement.

Answer (score 0):

Not an answer but too large/awkward for a comment.

Suggest starting the inner loop at `in + 1`.
Use the `index` rather than `in + index` in the inner loop.

```
for( int in = 0; in < N-1; in++ ) {
    // for( int index = 1; index < N; index++ )
    for( int index = in + 1; index < N; index++ )
    {
        // if( C[in] >= C[in+index] && C[in+index] <= C[in+1+index]  )
        // Also needs special handling when index is N-1
        if( C[in] >= C[index] && C[in] <= C[index+1]  )
        {
            num = num + 1;
        }
        // if( C[in] < C[in+index] )
        if( C[in] < C[index] )
        {
            break;
        }
    }
}
```